# Android emulator sound input: Use the host microphone or a sound stream as the source

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-audiorecord

I am trying to make the android emulator (v26) to be able to pick the host microphone or a sound stream as the source of sound input (like it was the physical device microphone).

My first try was to open the easy recorder application that comes with the system image, but when I try to open it the emulator crashes and reboots.

I am currently looking at other options, like [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) in a VirtualBox, but so far I haven't been able to even install it (I'm on it at this moment)

What I need to do is to have certain applications (third-party, from which I am not the developer) to receive sounds from the host machine as if the sound was received through the phone microphone.

One of the things that I need is to be able to launch multiple emulators at the same time on the host machine, and, as far as I understand (I'm very new in the Android world) with [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) you have access to the host microphone, but you have to pay for each instance that you want to run. Is that so?

My host machine is an ubuntu 16.10, but actually any linux flavor that can do it would work for me.

I don't seem to find a proper resource to help me figure it out, all the questions that I find here in stack overflow are a bit old, some people say that is impossible to use the microphone, others say that is possible but I don't seem to find how.

Comment: Android 7.1 installs and run in VirtualBox on Linux without much trouble.  I also would like to add microphone ability to do voice searching etc but so far do not have an answer for that.